# Iteratively calculate columns of a data.table one row at a time (recursive column definitions)

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, recursion, data.table

## Background/Example

Hi all,

I am trying to use existing columns within a data.table to calculate new columns. However, the columns rely on the previous row's value. For example, say my column *R<sub>t</sub> = A<sub>t</sub> + B<sub>t</sub> + R<sub>t-1</sub>*. I have two columns that make up my key, *scenario* and *t*. How I have been trying to do this is:

## Current solution:

```
for(i in 1:maxScenario){

for(j in 2:nrow(dt)) {

dt[scenario == i & t == j, "R"] <- dt[scenario == i & t == j - 1, "R"]
+ dt[scenario == i & t == j, "A"] + dt[scenario == i & t == j, "B"]

} # end for loop for t

} # end for loop for scenario
```

The distinction here is that after the "<-" I'm using *j - 1* instead of *j* for *R* to retrieve the previous row's value.

## Question

I realize this is adding a lot of computation time, and is a pretty rough way to go about this. Is there  a better way within the data.table package to do this? I have tried using *shift()* but ran into problems there. Using *shift()* doesn't "recalculate" the columns based on *A* and *B*.

I have considered using a recursive formula, but I wasn't sure what that would do to efficiency and run time. Ideally, I'm hoping to run about 100K scenarios and need these calculations tacked on after the stochastic scenarios are completed.

Thanks!

## Edit: Example

Here's an attempt at a small example. Each row's value of R depends on the value from the previous row.

```
t  R  A  B
1  0  1  2
2  3  2  3
3  8  2  5
4  15 8  5
5  28 10 8
```

## Edit 2: Further Clarification

I was finally able to translate my actual problem function into algebra:

*R<sub>t</sub>* = λ * P<sub>t</sub> + λ * R<sub>t-1</sub> - min{λ * P<sub>t</sub> + λ * R<sub>t-1</sub>, D<sub>t</sub>} - A(t) * max{λ * P<sub>t</sub> + λ * R<sub>t-1</sub> - D<sub>t</sub> - M<sub>t</sub>, 0} where P<sub>t</sub>, D<sub>t</sub>, and M<sub>t</sub> are other known columns and A(t) is an indicator function that returns 0 when t % 4 is != 0, and 1 otherwise.

Is there a way to use *shift()* and *cumsum()* with such a nested equation?

Comment: This question could be improved slightly using a small example ( say 6 rows of a data.frame with expected output ). As is it is not as simply to come up with an example, even though the question is well formulated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using `Rcpp` with `data.table` as its easier to think/code in `cpp` for recursive equation:

```
DT[, A := +(t %% 4 == 0)]

library(Rcpp)    
cppFunction('NumericVector recur(double lambda, NumericVector P, 
    NumericVector D, NumericVector M, NumericVector A) {
        int sz = P.size(), t;
        NumericVector R(sz);

        for (t=1; t<sz; t++) {
            R[t] = lambda * P[t] + lambda * R[t-1] -
                std::min(lambda * P[t] + lambda * R[t-1], D[t]) -
                A[t] * std::max(lambda * P[t] * lambda * R[t-1] - D[t] - M[t], 0.0);
        }

    return(R);
}')

DT[, R := recur(lambda, P, D, M, A)]
```

output:

```
     t            P           D          M A           R
 1:  1  1.262954285  0.25222345 -0.4333103 0  0.00000000
 2:  2 -0.326233361 -0.89192113 -0.6494716 0  0.72880445
 3:  3  1.329799263  0.43568330  0.7267507 0  0.59361856
 4:  4  1.272429321 -1.23753842  1.1519118 1  1.89610128
 5:  5  0.414641434 -0.22426789  0.9921604 0  1.37963924
 6:  6 -1.539950042  0.37739565 -0.4295131 0  0.00000000
 7:  7 -0.928567035  0.13333636  1.2383041 0  0.00000000
 8:  8 -0.294720447  0.80418951 -0.2793463 1  0.00000000
 9:  9 -0.005767173 -0.05710677  1.7579031 0  0.05422319
10: 10  2.404653389  0.50360797  0.5607461 0  0.72583032
11: 11  0.763593461  1.08576936 -0.4527840 0  0.00000000
12: 12 -0.799009249 -0.69095384 -0.8320433 1 -1.23154792
13: 13 -1.147657009 -1.28459935 -1.1665705 0  0.09499689
14: 14 -0.289461574  0.04672617 -1.0655906 0  0.00000000
15: 15 -0.299215118 -0.23570656 -1.5637821 0  0.08609900
16: 16 -0.411510833 -0.54288826  1.1565370 1  0.38018234
```

data:

```
library(data.table)    
set.seed(0L)
nr <- 16L
DT <- data.table(t=1L:nr, P=rnorm(nr), D=rnorm(nr), M=rnorm(nr))
lambda <- 0.5
```

Comment: I like this a lot! I was afraid I would have to import my vectors into C++ to run this recursively as I didn't realize there was such a package. How much do you expect the efficiency of this method to improve upon the iterative for loop I detailed in the question?

Comment: I can't get this to run, R tells me I have Rtools version 3.5 installed, but I've just installed Rtools40. What are you using to run it?

Comment: I switched my R version within "Global Options" and it seems to run now. Do we not need to give the recursive function a base case?

Comment: I am assuming R[0] = 0. If you like another starting value, we can pass it in. Rcpp should be fast enough

Answer (score 1):

This creates a new column `R2` wirth the same values as R

```
DT[, R2 := shift( cumsum(A+B), type = "lag", fill = 0 ) ][]

#    t  R  A B R2
# 1: 1  0  1 2  0
# 2: 2  3  2 3  3
# 3: 3  8  2 5  8
# 4: 4 15  8 5 15
# 5: 5 28 10 8 28
```

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks! I will put this into a second edit of the question, but I was finally able to translate my actual problem function into algebra:

R_t = λ * P_t + λ * R_t - min{λ * P_t + λ * R_t, D_t} - A(t) * max{λ * P_t + λ * R_t - D_t - M_t, 0} where P_t, D_t, and M_t are other known columns and A(t) is an indicator function that returns 0 when t % 4 is != 0, and 1 otherwise.

Is there a way to use *shift()* and *cumsum()* with such a nested equation?

Comment: please ask a new question, with a sample-data set (and desired output)...

Answer (score 1):

There is to my knowledge there is no way to iteratively calculate the rows with buildin functions from `data.table`. I even believe there's a duplicate question out there, that has a similar question (although I cannot find it right now).

We can however speed up the calculations by noting the tricks we could use in the formulation. First to obtain the result in the example provided, we can note this is just `cumsum(shift(A, 1, fill = 0) + shift(B, 1, fill = 0))`

```
dt <- fread('t  R  A  B
1  0  1  2
2  3  2  3
3  8  2  5
4  15 8  5
5  28 10 8') 
dt[, R2 := cumsum(shift(A, 1, fill = 0) + shift(B, 1, fill = 0))]
dt
   t  R  A B R2
1: 1  0  1 2  0
2: 2  3  2 3  3
3: 3  8  2 5  8
4: 4 15  8 5 15
5: 5 28 10 8 28
```

However for the exact problem described *R<sub>t</sub> = A<sub>t</sub> + B<sub>t</sub> + R<sub>t-1</sub>* we will have to be a bit smarter

```
dt[, R3 := cumsum(A + B) - head(A + B, 1)]
dt
   t  R  A B R2 R3
1: 1  0  1 2  0  0
2: 2  3  2 3  3  5
3: 3  8  2 5  8 12
4: 4 15  8 5 15 25
5: 5 28 10 8 28 43
```

Which follows the above description. Note that I remove the first row, with the assumption that `R0 = 0`, otherwise it simply becomes `cumsum(A + B)`

## Edit

As the question is asking for some possibly more complicated situations, I'll add an example using a slower (but more general) example. The idea here is to use the `set` function, to avoid intermediary shallow copes (see `help(set)` or `help("datatable-optimize")`).

```
dt[, R4 := 0]
for(i in seq.int(2, dt[, .N])){
  #dummy complicated scenario
  f <- dt[seq(i), lm(A ~ B - 1)]
  set(dt, i, 'R4', unname(unlist(coef(f))))
}
dt
t  R  A B R2 R3        R4
1: 1  0  1 2  0  0 0.0000000
2: 2  3  2 3  3  5 0.6153846
3: 3  8  2 5  8 12 0.4736842
4: 4 15  8 5 15 25 0.9206349
5: 5 28 10 8 28 43 1.0866142
```

Comment: Could you expand on what R3 and the *head()* function are doing? Also, I take it that using *cumsum()* and *shift()* is taking the place of the recursive variable?

Comment: see `?head` for info about it. `head(A + B, 1)` could be `head(A,1) + head(B,1)`, no?

Comment: Head basically takes the first N observations, so assuming that observations are ordered head(..., 1) takes the first observation.